# Skip confirmation page on node delete

Tags: nodes

I'm trying to skip delete confirmation page only for a content type in my site.
I found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10516417/bypass-node-delete-confirm-form-in-drupal) but I can't figure out how to modify this code to affect only a nodes in a content type. 
This is the code i found:

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
  $items['node/%node/delete']['page callback'] = 'my_node_delete_function';
  $items['node/%node/delete']['page arguments'] = array(1);
  $items['node/%node/delete']['module'] = 'mymodule';
}

function my_node_delete_function($node) {
  // Taken from node modules node_delete_confirm submit handler
  node_delete($node->nid);
  watchdog('content', '@type: deleted %title.', array('@type' => $node->type, '%title' => $node->title));
  drupal_set_message(t('@type %title has been deleted.', array('@type' => node_type_get_name($node), '%title' => $node->title)));

  // Do a drupal goto here to preserver the 'destination' parameter
  drupal_goto();
}
```

Comment: You can use rules module to set a rule to redirect to certain path after deleting a node from specific content type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just checking the node's type should be enough, and you can default to returning the standard deletion form:

```
function my_node_delete_function($node) {
  // If the node is of your custom type, delete it straight away.
  if ($node->type == 'my_type') {
    node_delete($node->nid);
    // ...
    drupal_goto();
  }
  else {
    // Otherwise, serve the standard node delete page.
    module_load_include('inc', 'node', 'node.pages');
    return drupal_get_form('node_delete_confirm', $node);
  }
}
```

Comment: With this code if I try to delete content of another content type I have only a white page in return

Comment: Try the updated code...